# The union of all intervals for each group

Tags: r

I have a following example dataset:

```
df <- data.frame("id" = c(1,2,3,3,4), 
                 "start" = c(01-01-2018,01-06-2018,01-05-2018,01-05-2018,01-05-2018, 01-10-2018),
                 "end" = c(01-03-2018,01-07-2018,01-09-2018,01-06-2018,01-06-2018,01-11-2018))

df$start <- as.Date(df$start, "%d-%m-%Y")
df$end <- as.Date(df$end, "%d-%m-%Y")
```

What I want to do with it is for each group to get a union of all date intervals), i.e.

01-01-2018  -  01-03-2018 for group 1

01-06-2018  -  01-06-2018 for group 2

01-05-2018  -  01-09-2018 for group 3

01-05-2018  -  01-06-2018 and 01-10-2018  -  01-11-2018 for group 4

The purpose of this is to have an interval as an output, because I need it to determine whether certain observation dates for the group fall in the intervals or not.

Comment: I would prefer the output as a lubridate interval, as the purpose of this is to find out, whether certain observations for each id are in the union of the time intervals for that id

Answer (score 0):

We convert the 'start', 'end' to `Date` class, then grouped by'id', created an `interval` column in `summarise` based on the `min` and `max` of the 'start', and 'end' columns respectively

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(lubridate)
df %>%
   mutate(across(c(start, end), mdy)) %>% 
   group_by(id) %>%
   summarise(interval =  interval(min(start), max(end)), .groups = 'drop')
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3, 3, 4), start = c("01-01-2018", 
"01-06-2018", "01-05-2018", "01-05-2018", "01-10-2018"), end = c("01-03-2018", 
"01-07-2018", "01-09-2018", "01-06-2018", "01-11-2018")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: The thing is that there is a possibility that a group will have multiple non-overlapping intervals, such as group 4 in my example (just noticed i didnt include last observation of group 4 in my example, sorry for that)